# entity framework and where with like

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, where-clause

I' m using this instruction:

```
db_user = db.CBR_User.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Codice_Fiscale == code);
```

I want use "like" operator instead == for manage case insensitive

How can do it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do an equality comparison anyway, I suggest two ways:

```
db_user = db.CBR_User.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Codice_Fiscale.Equals(code, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Or

```
db_user = db.CBR_User.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Codice_Fiscale.ToUpper() == code.ToUpper());
```

If you don't want that, you can use StartsWith, Contains, etc, with the parameter StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase.

Comment: I'd also note that depending on your database (sql 2008) may not be case-sensitive anyway.

Comment: Yes, indeed... it depends on the database

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Contains()`:

```
db_user = db.CBR_User.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Codice_Fiscale.Contains(code));
```

Comment: -1 Contains() can be used to replace a SQL like. However, it is case sensitive and has no built-in case insensitive equivalent.  Review the remarks section of the MSDN article on Contains:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

Comment: Contains is translated to `LIKE` in SQL and there it _is_ case insensitive. `WHERE Name LIKE '%rob%'` returns the same results as `WHERE Name LIKE '%ROB%'`.

Comment: In fact case sensitiveness of `LIKE` depends on the collation setting in the database. The MSDN link you mentioned has nothing to do with the SQL generated by EF.

Comment: The case sensitivity of LIKE is indeed based on the collation in the database.  However, the reason I found this question was precisely because Contains was behaving case sensitive even though the collation of the column was insensitive and I was looking for case insensitive alternatives to Contains.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but to expand on what [Kristof Claes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259106/kristof-claes) was saying,

```
db_user = db.CBR_User.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Codice_Fiscale.ToUpper().Contains(code.ToUpper()));
```

if you use the ToUpper option, it will act as if it is a case insensitive search.  You could use ToLower to do the same thing, in case you have that penchant.

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ To Entity you have functions like StartsWith, EndsWith and Contains that you can use instead like