# LIKE query with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008-r2, ef-code-first

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do SQL Like % in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq)
>   [Like Operator in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033007/like-operator-in-entity-framework)

I'm doing a query like this:

```
    var matches = from m in db.Customers
        where m.Name == key
        select m;
```

But I don't need `m.Name` to be exactly equal to key. I need `m.Name` to be like key.

I can't find how to recreate the SQL query:

```
    WHERE m.Name LIKE key
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

How to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicates: [Like Operator in Entity Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033007), [How to write like statements...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202217), [Entity Framework v4.1 LIKE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202036), [How to do a SQL LIKE...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689284),[entity framework and where with like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958082),[How do I do a “like” wildcard comparison in Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376191)

Comment: are you familiar with CHARINDEX I will post an example if you would like

Comment: @mellamokb Will see it. Thanks.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Post the example please, Thanks.

Comment: CHARINDEX is equivalent, with slightly better performance.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Would something like this linq query work for you.. ?

```
var matches = from m in db.Customers
    where m.Name.Contains(key)      
    select m;
```

this should also work I edited my answer.

`Contains` is mapped to LIKE '%@p0%' which is case insensitive

Comment: What language is that written in exactly?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will do some tests with charindex.

Comment: @mellamokb C# WPF. Using EF Code First. SQLServer 2008 R2

Comment: That looks like SQL and LINQ combined, which doesn't work.

Comment: DJ KRAZE I have few experience with this site. I believe I selected this answer. Let me know if I did something wrong (the -1 vote) and how to correct it.

Comment: I have this working for me but I was assuming you were using entity with SQL my mistake.. Andrew's answer should work perfectly for you

Comment: Note that the code in this answer will not compile.

Comment: sorry I had a typo had m.Names instead of m.Name

Comment: well I need that Negative to be removed .. since the answer is also a working solution..thanks

Answer (score 25):

```
var matches = from m in db.Customers     
    where m.Name.StartsWith(key)
    select m;
```

Make the search and compare whether the string is either lowercase or uppercase to get the best result since C# is case-sensitive.

```
var matches = from m in db.Customers     
    where m.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(key.ToLower())
    select m;
```

Comment: It only covers one case but I can use EndsWith, Contains, etc. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Andrew, Contains works better for my needs but your answer was very useful. Thanks.