# MVC: Search by name of the video

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

Hi I have a question how can I improve my code that I can search through my database by putting at least one letter in textbox not all the title. Now it's searching but I need to put whole title to search something.

My search bar:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchVideo", "Video", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left", @role = "search" }))
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.TextBox("searchVideo", (object)null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Wyszukaj film" })
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    }
```

My VideoListViewModel:

```
public class VideoListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Video> VideoList { get; set; }
}
```

My searching View:

```
    <div class="list-group">
        @foreach (var video in Model.VideoList)
        {
            <a href="/Video/GetVideo?id=@video.Id" class="list-group-item clearfix">
                <img src="~/Images/@video.ImageUrl" style="width: 80px; height: 100px; padding: 5px;" />
                Premiere: @video.Date
                <br/>
            </a>
            <br/>
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: That I need to type whole title to search not part of the title.

Comment: You want to be able to search on a title fragment?

Comment: Yes, because not everyone knows the whole title of the movie. So it could be a little facilitation

Comment: See this [LIKE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786664/like-query-with-entity-framework) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Contains` method inside your where clause

```
return db.Video.Where(x => x.VideoName.Contains(search));
```

Contains method returns `true` when a string exist **anywhere** in the other string. If you are looking to get the records where the VideoName starts with the search parameter value ,you may use `StartsWith` method.

```
return db.Video.Where(x => x.VideoName.StartsWith(search));
```